# Bootstrap Switch status not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

Switch status not working for datatable : I have switches in html string have been checked and unchecked for the DB values. It is not working for the else part only the active/checked switch is shown but the unchecked witch status is not displayed... Please check my condition if it is wrong....ASAP.....Regards....

```
$.each(checkUser, function(index, act){
                                console.log(act.accountEnabled);
                                **if(act.accountEnabled){   
                                     enableDisable = " <input id='switch-user' name='switch-user' type='checkbox' checked data-size='mini' data-on-label='Enable' data-off-label='Disable'>";

                                } else{
                                    enableDisable = " <input id='switch-user' name='switch-user' type='checkbox' data-size='mini' data-on-label='Enable' data-off-label='Disable'>";**

                                }
                                console.log(enableDisable);
                            }); 

var userData = data.users;
        var dataSet = [];
        $.each(userData, function(index, user){
            dataSet.push([
                user.name,
                user.userId,
                user.creationTime,
                user.accountEnabled,
                user.roleName,
                userActions,
                enableDisable
            ]);
        });


        var oTable = $('table#user-datatable').dataTable( {
            "data": dataSet,
            "bFilter": false,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bInfo": false,
            "columnDefs": [ 
                { "targets": 5, "orderable": false, "width": "180px" },
                {"targets": 6, "orderable": false, "width": "60px" }

            ],
            "tableTools": {
                "sRowSelect": "single"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "title": "Name" },
                { "title": "UserId" },
                { "title": "CreationTime"},
                { "title": "Account Enabled" },
                { "title": "Role" },
                { "title": "Action"},
                {"title" : "Enable/Disable"}
            ],
            "fnInitComplete" : function(settings, json){
                $("input#switch-user").bootstrapSwitch();
            }
        });
```

Comment: <input id='switch-user' name='switch-user' type='checkbox' data-size='mini' data-on-label='Enable' data-off-label='Disable'>

Comment: my console is showing correct string but switch state is not rendered by the page or data table..it is showing for only true condition.....

Comment: when you are using plugins please put the official link of that plugin in your question so that others don't have to go and find what plugin you are using.

Comment: also its better if you could re produce the problem in a fiddle and share with us.

Comment: Thanks, Cerlin my issue was resolved as I am using jquery data table,bootstrap switch..my issue was where I am creating the column rows that is where i am pushing in to data set i have to check my condition there only. So, not the status is populating fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var userData = data.users;
        var dataSet = [];
        $.each(userData, function(index, user){
            if(user.accountEnabled){   
                                     enableDisable = " <input id='switch-user' name='switch-user' type='checkbox' checked data-size='mini' data-on-label='Enable' data-off-label='Disable'>";
                                } 
                                else{
                                    enableDisable = " <input id='switch-user' name='switch-user' type='checkbox' data-size='mini' data-on-label='Enable' data-off-label='Disable'>";**
                                }
            dataSet.push([
                user.name,
                user.userId,
                user.creationTime,
                user.accountEnabled,
                user.roleName,
                userActions,
                enableDisable
            ]);
        });
```